# C# closing mysql connection is not working, mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm getting this error on phpMyAdmin

```
mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections
```

The only script that is using this DB:

```
public static bool checkIp(string ip)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CHECKIP");

            try
            {
                string sql = " SELECT * FROM `Ip tables` ";
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=hostname;user=username;password=password;database=database;");
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (ip == reader.GetString("Ip"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Benvenuto, " + reader.GetString("Name"));
                        con.Close();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return false;
            }
            catch(SqlException exp)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Error", exp);
            }
        }
```

Does this code close the connection correctly or something is wrong?

EDIT:
I added this block after the catch block

```
    finally
    {
        if(con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any better way to write the code? Would finaly block still run if return is executed?

Comment: Connection pooling operates by unique connection strings. Do you have many simultaneous users and does the connection string change for each one (username/password)?

Comment: `mysqli_connect` is a PHP function. The code you showed seems to be C#. What do you mean?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yeah, I do have simultaneous users with the same connection string. Didn't thing about it, is there a way to do the same withouth change user and password for each user?

Comment: the first snippet says, your phpmyadmin gets trouble as another program uses too many connection (possibly for the same user) and it no longer able to connect to the mysq. you should reduce the number of connection you made to mysql in your c# app, the `MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=ho...` can be enclosed in [`using-finally` or `try-finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-finally-blocks) block. this to ensure you actually close the connection if you hit the catch block. cmiiw.

Comment: You could use a service account to share a username and password but that is pretty insecure unless you move data access to an external service/api. If you are on Windows then I believe MySql supports Windows Integrated Security which will keep the connection string the same for everyone. If you are getting exceptions it may help a little to ensure the connection is closed in a `finally` block or in a `using` statement as Bagus mentioned.

Comment: Pretty obvious that your code is hitting the exception handler, where you don't close the connection. Use a `using` statement as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your query in a using statement like this:

```
string conString= "host=hostname;user=username;password=password;database=database;"

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `Ip tables`";

                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                         while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (ip == reader.GetString("Ip"))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Benvenuto, " + reader.GetString("Name"));
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This will automatically close the connection without having to state `con.Close()`